# Multiple columns in subquery: SQLite, MS SQL Server

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, edx

How to rewrite this SQL query [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/b6f01/32/0) without using multiple column selection in WHERE section.

Comment: What is your question exactly? Sql server doesn't support that syntax, like it doesn't support many other syntaxes supported by SQLite and/or MySQL (or other dbms's, for that matter). The other way around is equally true.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax `(hs1.ID,hs2.ID,hs3.ID) IN ...`

Is not supported in SQL Server.

You can only have 1 column or variable on the left side of an `IN` statement.

You can rewrite it using EXISTS:

```
SELECT hs1.name
    ,hs1.grade
    ,hs2.name
    ,hs2.grade
    ,hs3.name
    ,hs3.grade
FROM highschooler AS hs1
    ,highschooler AS hs2
    ,highschooler AS hs3
WHERE EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM friend AS fr1
        JOIN (
            SELECT ls.ID1
                ,ls.ID2
            FROM likes AS ls
            WHERE  NOT EXISTS (
                    SELECT f.ID1
                        ,f.ID2
                    FROM friend AS f
                    WHERE f.ID1 = ls.ID1
                    AND f.ID2 = ls.ID2
                    )
            ) AS X ON fr1.ID1 = X.ID1
        JOIN friend AS fr2 ON X.ID2 = fr2.ID1
        WHERE fr1.ID2 = fr2.ID2
            AND hs1.ID = X.ID1
            AND hs2.ID = X.ID2
            AND hs3.ID = fr1.ID2
        )
```

[SQL Fiddle in SQL Server](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/f7b2b/6/0)

Comment: What does "SELECT 1 .." means in above context?

Comment: The moment 1 row matches, the condition is met. The 1 is just a dummy column value, you can `select 'whateveryouwant'` and it will still work.